# How to return view with flash message?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, alert

What i need is this:

```
return view('protected.standardUser.includes.documents',compact('documents'))->with('successMsg','Property is updated .');
```

The i could use it like this:

```
  @if(Session::has('successMsg'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ Session::get('successMsg') }}</div>
  @endif
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: laravel 5.2 im using...its in tag..and like u see i tried 'with' but its not working

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing two different ways of passing data to a view, which I'm guessing is the problem. [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views) seems to indicate it's a one or the other type situation. You also seem to be mixing up `view()->with()` and `redirect()->with()`, which work differently. Try this:

```
return view('protected.standardUser.includes.documents')->with('documents', $documents)->with('successMsg','Property is updated .');
```

And

```
@if(!empty($successMsg))
  <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ $successMsg }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Is there something broken here in Laravel 9, or is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 16):

I order to use session stored flash messages, need to use following code into `route method`.

```
 $request->session()->flash('successMsg','Saved succesfully!');
```

and then do

```
 @if(Session::has('successMsg'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ Session::get('successMsg') }}</div>
  @endif
```

that's it

Comment: How to unset flash message from the session?

Answer (score 3):

I'm new in Laravel and I was facing the same issue... I just tried as below::

```
\Session::flash('flash','Message info');
```

And it works!!

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me!**

```
return view('protected.standardUser.includes.documents',compact('documents'),
['successMsg'=>'Property is updated .']);
```

> just remove the `with()` and pass it in the `return view()`

Comment: This doesn't add the message into the session to retrieve with `Session::get`. It does the same as `with()`.