# Laravel - Avoiding double-booking time slots

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to figure out how I would add some form of validation so that the same theatre slot cannot be booked twice on the same date. Any advice is much appreciated.

The code below is how to crete a booking, at present the user has a set list of options within the form to choose a theatre time slot in the TheatreRoomID field. The date is selected with the Form::Date input.

**Bookings - Create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<hr>
<h1>Booking Form</h1>
<hr>
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'BookingFormsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('requestID', 'Request ID')}}
{{Form::number('requestID', $patientDetail->requestID, ['class' => 'form-control',])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('requestDate', 'Request Date')}}
{{Form::date('requestDate', $patientDetail->requestDate, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('patientID', 'Patient ID')}}
{{Form::number('patientID', $patientDetail->patientID, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('patientForename', 'Patient Forename')}}
{{Form::text('patientForename', $patientDetail->patientForename, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('patientSurname', 'Patient Surname')}}
{{Form::text('patientSurname', $patientDetail->patientSurname, ['class' => 'form-control',])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('patientSex', 'Patient Sex')}}
{{Form::text('patientSex', $patientDetail->patientSex, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('patientDOB', 'Patient DOB')}}
{{Form::date('patientDOB', $patientDetail->patientDOB, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('patientUrgency', 'Patient Urgency')}}
{{Form::text('patientUrgency', $patientDetail->patientUrgency, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('TheatreRoomID', 'Theatre Room')}}
{{Form::select('TheatreRoomID', ['Room 1 - Time: 9:00AM - 11:00AM' => 'Room 1 - Time: 9:00AM - 11:00AM',
                                'Room 1 - Time: 12:00PM -2:00PM' => 'Room 1 - Time: 12:00PM - 2:00PM',
                                'Room 1 - Time: 3:00PM - 5:00PM' => 'Room 1 - Time: 3:00PM - 5:00PM',
                                'Room 2 - Time: 9:00AM - 11:00AM' => 'Room 2 - Time: 9:00AM - 11AM',
                                'Room 2 - Time: 12:00PM - 2:00PM' => 'Room 2 - Time: 12:00PM - 2:00PM',
                                'Room 2 - Time: 3:00PM - 5:00PM' => 'Room 2 - Time: 3:00PM - 5:00PM',
                                'Room 3 - Time: 9:00AM - 11:00AM' => 'Room 3 - Time: 9:00AM - 11:00AM',
                                'Room 3 - Time: 12:00PM - 2:00PM' => 'Room 3 - Time: 12:00PM - 2:00PM',
                                'Room 3 - Time: 3:00PM - 5:00PM' => 'Room 3 - Time: 3:00PM - 5:00PM'

                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Select Theatre Slot'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('surgeryType', 'Surgery Type')}}
{{Form::text('surgeryType', $patientDetail->surgeryType, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('surgeryDate', 'Surgery Date')}}
  {{Form::date('surgeryDate')}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('performingSurgeon', 'Peforming Surgeon')}}
  {{Form::select('performingSurgeon', ['Wendy clarke' => 'Wendy Clarke', 'John Kennedy' => 'John Kennedy', 'Imran Yousuf' => 'Imran Yousuf', 'Merideth Grey' => 'Merideth Grey', 'Derek Shepherd' => 'Derek Shepherd'], null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => ''])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{{Form::label('bloodGroup', 'Blood Group')}}
{{Form::select('bloodGroup', ['A' => 'A', 'B' => 'B', 'O' => 'O', 'AB' => 'AB'], null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => $patientDetail->bloodGroup])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('patientNotes', 'Patient Notes')}}
  {{Form::textarea('patientNotes', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter any other neccessary patient details'])}}
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar">
  <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-danger mr-3">Back</a>
  {{Form::submit('Submit Booking', ['class'=> 'btn btn-success mr-3'])}}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

**BookingFormController:**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('bookingforms.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $booking)
{
  $this->validate($booking, [
  'requestID' => 'required',
  'patientID' => 'required',
  'patientForename' => 'required',
  'patientSurname'=> 'required',
  'patientSex' => 'required',
  'patientDOB' => 'required',
  'surgeryType' => 'required',
  'surgeryDate' => 'required',
  'performingSurgeon' => 'required',
  'TheatreRoomID' => 'required',
  'patientUrgency' => 'required',
  'patientNotes' => 'required',
  'bloodGroup' => 'required'
  ]);

  // Create new Booking Form
  $bookingform = new Bookingform;
  $bookingform->requestID = $booking->input('requestID');
  $bookingform->bookingID = $booking->input('bookingID');
  $bookingform->patientID = $booking->input('patientID');
  $bookingform->patientForename = $booking->input('patientForename');
  $bookingform->patientSurname = $booking->input('patientSurname');
  $bookingform->patientSex = $booking->input('patientSex');
  $bookingform->patientDOB = $booking->input('patientDOB');
  $bookingform->surgeryType = $booking->input('surgeryType');
  $bookingform->surgeryDate = $booking->input('surgeryDate');
  $bookingform->performingSurgeon = $booking->input('performingSurgeon');
  $bookingform->TheatreRoomID = $booking->input('TheatreRoomID');
  $bookingform->patientUrgency = $booking->input('patientUrgency');
  $bookingform->patientNotes = $booking->input('patientNotes');
  $bookingform->bloodGroup = $booking->input('bloodGroup');

  //Save Booking form

  $bookingform->save();

  //redirect
  return redirect('/bookingforms')->with('success', 'Booking Submitted');
}
```

**BookingForm.php Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BookingForm extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'bookingforms';
  //primary key
  public $primaryKey = 'bookingID';
  //Timestamps
  public $timestamps = true;
}
```

**BookingForms Table Structure:**
[see table structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr6ev.png)

I am fairly new to Laravel so any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: First of all, you might want to set some constraints at database level. We need to know how you're storing your data so there's relevant information you'll need to show us: The code of your models and the schema of your tables.

Comment: Hi there, I have updated the question to include the model code and table structure :)

Comment: use `unique` which field do you unique like this `  'home_id' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:homes'],` where `homes` is a model

Comment: How are you defining the time availability for each room at database level? That's the key of this

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [**Middleware**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#defining-middleware):

- First you define a Middleware using this command `php artisan make:middleware MiddlewareName`

I've already defind mine with the name `CheckTheatre`

So what **Middleware** does is filter the HTTP requests entering your application.

Like **this**:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\BookingForm;
use Closure;

class CheckTheatre
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       return BookingForm::where([['surgeryDate',$request->input('surgeryDate')],
            ['TheatreRoomID',$request->input('TheatreRoomID')]])->exists() ? 
            redirect('home'):$next($request);
    }
}
```

so what this function does is check for the existence of a record with the same date and `TheatreRoomID` of the current request, (I assumed the date you're referring to is the `surgeryDate`)
 If there is a record it redirects him to `home`, **But** you can return an Error message if you like.
 And if there wasn't any record then the request passes and `store` is called.

Now after you made the function to handle the request you need to tell the Middleware which request to handle.
So in`routes.web` You can call the middleware like this:

```
Route::post('bookingoffer', 'yourController@store')->middleware('MiddlewareName');
```

And make sure you add the Middleware you made to `app/Http/Kernel.php`

## Suggestion

Read [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) & [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation) it will make your controller much more readable and makes coding easier in general.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm away from my PC at the moment but I will give this a go as soon as im back and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Stupid question, do I add this into my booking forms controller?

Comment: Even tho this will work, OP might want to tell the user what happened so Laravel validations is a better way to go. OP you might want to read about Middlewares in the documentation if you go this route.

Comment: Is there a way to use Laravel Validation to achieve this? Or would middleware be the most straightforward method?

Comment: @AndrewGlenny No you don't need to add this to the `BookingForm`, The created Middleware will be in `App/Http/Middleware` Folder. Regarding Laravel validation i don't think you can validate 2 values at the same time, But it may be possible through custom [validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) but that would make things too complicated.

Comment: Ok no problem, I really appreciate the help thank you!

Comment: @Makdous I have added the middleware in but now seem to be getting the follow error when attempting to submit a booking - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select exists(select * from `bookingforms` where (`0` = surgeryDate and `1` = 2020-02-10)) as `exists`)                                              Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Just tried, getting the following error now:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TheatreRoomID ' in 'where clause' (SQL: select exists(select * from `bookingforms` where (`surgeryDate` = 2020-08-05 and `TheatreRoomID ` = Room 2 - Time: 9:00AM - 11:00AM)) as `exists`)

Comment: I added the middle middleware into the "protected $routeMiddleware" section of Kernel.php like this - 'CheckTheatre' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckTheatre::class, would this have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: also in my routes I have the following route: "  Route::resource('bookingforms', 'BookingFormsController');" , I added "  Route::post('bookingforms/index', 'BookingFormsController@store')->middleware('CheckTheatre');" beneath it

Comment: @AndrewGlenny I'm sorry there is a white-space after `TheatreRoomID` i fixed it, it should work now

Comment: @Makdous Apologies, I should've picked that up, thats it now, thank you very much!

Comment: I hate to ask another question, but do you have any idea how I would go about adding a message when the user is redirected to say 'This Theatre Slot has already been booked on this date'?

Comment: @AndrewGlenny see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417865/how-to-return-view-with-flash-message), And feel free to ask anytime.